# How to retrieve Selected Value of a PropertiesComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, devexpress, aspxgridview

i am having issue with getting the selected index or even the selected value of a PropertiesComboBox.

I have seen the properties but there is no method to get the value or index.

Does anyone know how to do this?

> > GridViewDataComboBoxColumn valueComboBox = gridViewPromo.Columns["Value"] as GridViewDataComboBoxColumn;
> >
> > valueComboBox.PropertiesComboBox??

I am casting a GridViewDataComboBoxColumn, then getting the PropertiesComboBox property from it. This is in a ASPXGridView...

Comment: Is it `<asp:ListBox>?`? what control are you using? Please add the code and 3rd party link if you use other than asp.net#

Comment: @user3032507: is this `devexpress` ??

Comment: @user3032507: Since this is a third party control, I recommend you to post the question [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/) as well!!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty just posted it, thanks